# Is there an optimized version of counting bloom filters for the case when counts are very large?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, concurrency, clock, bloom-filter

I became curious about this after seeing [this paper on bloom clocks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.13064). The basic idea is that a counting bloom filter, which supports both the sum (counterwise sum) and union (counterwise max) of multisets, can be used as a compromise between scalar Lamport clocks and vector clocks, where each node increments a hash-determined subset of the counters by 1 on an event.

Taking an example like 16 counters with each node incrementing 3 of them you still get a clock that is fairly good at finding runs of a thousand causally unrelated events in the high concurrency limit where many events can have similar timestamps.

However, for a practical implementation of things like causally ordered message topics where you can end up with more than 4 billion events in a strict sequence, you still need the counting bloom filter to use 64-bit counters.

This made me wonder if there are specialized data structures to minimize space usage for the very specific case of a probabilistic multiset with very large counts, that needs to support multiset sum and union?

Answer (score 0):

You can use floating point counters.

For example, lets say you store a counter as a pair of 8-bits numbers `(e,m)`, representing the count `m << e`.

When incrementing a counter:

- if `e > 0`, then the counter is missing `e` low-order bits.  In order to compensate for that, you randomly decide whether or not to increment `m`, with probability 2<sup>-e</sup>
- If incrementing `m` would overflow its 8 bits, then increment `e` and shift `m` to the right.

Of course, this makes the counters a little bit inaccurate, but the expected inaccuracy is small compared to the count.

Comment: However, the clock scheme above will make the integers correlated because they bleed into each other, so actors whose clocks are falling behind often end up having to increment their clocks. So compression schemes that rely on most counters having the same high bits may work.